# How can I determine what causes app to stop running

Tags: android, exception, performance-testing, runtimeexception

My app compiles without issue, other than a warning about cursor deprecation, and is deployed and runs correctly but stops after a few minutes and asks 'open app again?'. It reopens correctly.

The crash report is below but I have no idea how to interpret it.
The app is a simple database that shows steel section properties.
Any suggestions on where to start looking gratefully received.

The code of all 3 activities is here
http://silverfernsolutions.com/Code_for_stackoverflow_55308480.txt

Min version code is below. I can only test this on the Studio AVD by getting to the DisplaySectionProperties screen and then turning the emulator off and on. The display reverts to ShowSelectedSource screen when turned back on and sometimes triggers the error message.

UPDATE-RESOLVED The problem goes away when the lines

```
    c.close();
    mDbHelper.close();
```

in DisplaySectionProperties onCreate() are removed. This implies it is a problem with the way the DB is being used and that is a different question.

```
  a java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3790)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3830)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.Activity.performRestart (Activity.java:7322)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:7353)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3765)
```

CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

String DB_NAME = "SteelSectionProperties";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Display icon in the toolbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);  //7Aug2011. Reload each time to pick up any upgrades

    DataBaseHelperReign myDbHelper;// = new DataBaseHelperReign(this);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelperReign(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to create DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to open DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        throw sqle;
    }
    myDbHelper.close();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String units = prefs.getString("displayunitskey", "1");
    if (units == "1") {
        //first use. Set mm as initial default setting
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("displayunitskey", "mm");
        editor.commit();
    }
}//end oncreate


public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
    int Idx = 0;
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn0: Idx = 0; break;
        case R.id.btn1: Idx = 1; break;
        case R.id.btn2: Idx = 2; break;
        case R.id.btn3: Idx = 3; break;
        case R.id.btn4: Idx = 4; break;
        case R.id.btn5: Idx = 5; break;
        case R.id.btn6: Idx = 6; break;
        case R.id.btn7: Idx = 7; break;
    } //end switch
    runIntents(Idx);
}//end onClick

/**/
private void runIntents(int idx) {
    if (idx == 0) {
        //Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSectionInput.class);
        //startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowSelectedSource.class);
        i.putExtra("ButtonID", idx);
        startActivity(i);
    } //endif
}//end runintents
}



 public class ShowSelectedSource extends ListActivity{
    long mSelSectionID;
    String mSource, mSourceFile;
    String mTable;
    private SectionsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private SectionsUserDbAdapter mDbUserHelper;
    private int BtnId;
    TextView tv_section, lblListSection;
    ImageView imgListSection;
    ImageView imgIcon;
    Button btn6;  //Tee shape
    String mSorting ="DESC";  //ASC or DESC (default)
    String mShape="A";         //default

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_selected_source);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        BtnId = bundle.getInt("ButtonID");
        lblListSection= findViewById(R.id.lblListSection);
        imgListSection= findViewById(R.id.imgListSection);
        btn6 =  findViewById(R.id.btn6);

        mDbHelper = new SectionsDbAdapter(this);
        mDbUserHelper = new SectionsUserDbAdapter(this);

        //Button clicked on opening screen
        switch (BtnId){
            case 0://custom, already gone in Main to section input screen
            case 1: mSource="CU"; mSourceFile="Saved user sections"; break; //user saved sections
            case 2: mSource="US"; mSourceFile="American   ";  break;
            case 3: mSource="AU"; mSourceFile="Australian  ";  break;
            case 4: mSource="UK"; mSourceFile="British   ";  break;
            case 5: mSource="EU"; mSourceFile="European   ";  break;
            case 6: mSource="JA"; mSourceFile="Japan   ";  break;
            case 7: mSource="TU"; mSourceFile="Tubes   ";  break;
        }//end switch

        if ( BtnId == 1){
            mTable="SectionUser";
            mDbUserHelper.open();
        }else{
            mTable="SectionProps";
            mDbHelper.open();
            btn6.setVisibility(View.GONE); //turn off Tee button
        }
        initialDisplay();

    } // end onCreate   ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void initialDisplay(){
        //open display
        lblListSection.setText(mSourceFile);
        Cursor c=null;
        try{
            if ( BtnId == 1){
                c = mDbUserHelper.fetchRecordsbySource(mTable, mSource);
            }else{
                c = mDbHelper.fetchRecordsbySourceReverse(mTable, mSource,mSorting);
            }
            startManagingCursor(c);
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] from = new String[] {SectionsDbAdapter.KEY_DESC };  //The column(s) that the data are from
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tv_full_width }; // int array containing references to the views that we'll bind the data into (the R.id.text1 TextView).

        SimpleCursorAdapter records =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.section_row_full_width, c, from, to);  //the .xml file containing the R.id.xxxx
        setListAdapter(records);
        //c.close();  don't close, it stuffs up the buttons for some reason
    }

   private void loadListView(){
        setImage();
        Cursor c=null;
        try{
            if (mShape.equals("A")){
                if ( BtnId == 1){
                    c = mDbUserHelper.fetchRecordsbySourceReverse(mTable, mSource,mSorting);
                }else{
                    c = mDbHelper.fetchRecordsbySourceReverse(mTable, mSource, mSorting);
                }
            }else{
                if ( BtnId == 1){
                    c = mDbUserHelper.fetchRecordsbySourceShapeReverse(mTable, mSource, mShape, mSorting);
                }else{
                    c = mDbHelper.fetchRecordsbySourceShapeReverse(mTable, mSource, mShape, mSorting);
                }
            }
            startManagingCursor(c);

            String[] from = new String[] {SectionsDbAdapter.KEY_DESC };  //The column(s) that the data are from
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tv_full_width }; // int array containing references to the views that we'll bind the data into (the R.id.text1 TextView).

            SimpleCursorAdapter records =
                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.section_row_full_width, c, from, to);  //the .xml file containing the R.id.xxxx
            setListAdapter(records);
            //c.close();  don't close, it stuffs up the buttons for some reason

        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }//end loadview

    //get button clicks for filtering
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {

        switch ( v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn0: mShape="A" ;break; //all
            case R.id.btn1: mShape="I";break;
            case R.id.btn2: mShape="["; break;
            case R.id.btn3: mShape="[]"; break;
            case R.id.btn4: mShape="O";break;
            case R.id.btn5: mShape="L";break;
            case R.id.btn6: mShape="T";break;
            case R.id.btnsort:
                if (mSorting.equals("DESC")){
                    mSorting="ASC";
                } else {
                    mSorting="DESC";
                }
                break;
        } //end switch

        loadListView();
    }//end onClick buttons

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); // Get the item that was clicked
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(127, 255, 0));

        // next screen to display properties
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplaySectionProperties.class);
        i.putExtra("ButtonID",BtnId);
        i.putExtra("Table",mTable);
        i.putExtra("TablerowID", id);
        Log.e("in select, Tablerow", " id = " +id);
        startActivity(i);

    }// end onclick listview
}  //end class


    public class DisplaySectionProperties extends AppCompatActivity {

private String mTable;
private long mTablerowID;
private int mBtnId;

private String mShape;
private String mDescription;
private double mDepth, mtw,mb1, mt1, mb2, mt2;
private String mDisplayUnits; // the units the user wants displayed
private String mSectionUnits; //the units that mS is currently using
private TextView txtDescription;
private ImageView imgShape;

//The section object
private cSectionProperties mS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_section_properties);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mS= new cSectionProperties();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
    mDisplayUnits=prefs.getString("displayunitskey","1");

    txtDescription= findViewById(R.id.lblDisplaySection);
    imgShape= findViewById(R.id.imgDisplaySection);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    mBtnId = bundle != null ? bundle.getInt("ButtonID") : 0;
    mTable = bundle != null ? bundle.getString("Table") : null;
    mTablerowID= bundle.getLong("TablerowID");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disp Sect TablerowID := " + mTablerowID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();

    if (mTablerowID == 0){
        //user input section
        mDescription=bundle.getString("Description");
        mDepth=bundle.getDouble("Depth");
        mtw=bundle.getDouble("tw");
        mb1=bundle.getDouble("B1");
        mt1=bundle.getDouble("T1");
        mb2=bundle.getDouble("B2");
        mt2=bundle.getDouble("T2");
        mShape=bundle.getString("Shape");
        mSectionUnits=bundle.getString("Units");
        //createUserSection();

    }else{

        Cursor c;
        try{

            if(mTable.equals("SectionUser") ){
                SectionsUserDbAdapter mDbHelper = new SectionsUserDbAdapter(this);
                mDbHelper.open();
                c = mDbHelper.fetchRecordbyID(mTable, mTablerowID+""); //convert int to string (v= v + "")= int V is now string
                startManagingCursor(c);
                mDescription= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Description"));
                mDepth= c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Depth"));
                mtw = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("tweb_wall"));
                mb1= c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Bf1"));
                mt1= c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Tf1"));
                mb2= c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Bf2"));
                mt2= c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Tf2"));
                mShape= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Shape"));
                mSectionUnits= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Units"));
                c.close();
                mDbHelper.close();

                //createUserSection();

            }else{
                // section from the standard DB, mSectionUnits will be mm
                SectionsDbAdapter mDbHelper = new SectionsDbAdapter(this);
                mDbHelper.open();
                c = mDbHelper.fetchRecordbyID(mTable, mTablerowID+""); //convert int to string (v= v + "")= int V is now string
                startManagingCursor(c);
                mDbHelper.close();
               // createSection(c);
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//endif

   // displayProperties();


} //end oncreate
```

Comment: Looks like problem may be related to threading. It would be easier to find reason of crash if you share your code.

Comment: The app has 3 activities. 1 has buttons to select countries 2 shows listview of sections for that country 3 shows properties of the user selected section from 2. If I only use activities 1 and 2 then the app is stable (but not particularly useful). Selecting the section and displaying 3 works but after a few minutes, or less, the app closes with the error. The code for activities are larger than permitted for this site so I have added a link above

Comment: Make an [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Minimal code added, but only possible to test on the ADV.

Comment: The reason for the crashing is determined and resolved but the way the DB is handled will be reviewed. This might lead to different question being asked. Thanks for your input